# Filling ListView with ObservableCollection (Windows Store App)

Tags: listview, data-binding, observablecollection

So I have a ListView with an ItemTemplate that I want to fill with the contents of an ObservableCollection and I haven't been succesful in doing so.

The ItemTemplate:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="templateIngredient">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding GetIngredient}"></TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
```

The ListView:

```
<ListView x:Name="listViewIngredienten" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource templateIngredient}" SelectionMode="None">
                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,-5,0,-5"></Setter>
                    </Style>
                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ListView>
```

The DataSource:

```
    public class RecipeDataItem
{
    public String UniqueId { get; set; }
    public String Title { get; set; }
    public String ShortTitle { get; set; }
    public String Country { get; set; }
    public String Directions { get; set; }
    public int Preptime { get; set; }
    public int Rating { get; set; }
    public int ImageId { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<String> Ingredients { get; set; }

        public String GetIngredient
    {
        get
        {
            foreach (var ingredient in Ingredients)
            {
                return ingredient;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I had to write the "return null;" because I otherwise get the error that not all codepaths return a value.

Can anyone help me to get this working? I can provide more code if necessary though I think the problem lies within the GetIngredient code. When I simply return the first value of the ObservableCollection and use a TextBlock instead of a ListView to pick it up it works.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who care, my mistake was the binding in the datatemplate. I binded it to a function in my class (getIngredient) while it should have been just {Binding}.

```
<Page.Resources>
<DataTemplate x:Key="templateIngredient">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"></TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
```

After that I gave the listview an itemssource in my code:

```
private async void navigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e) { var item = RecipeDataSource.getItem((String)e.NavigationParameter); this.DefaultViewModel["Item"] = item; listViewIngredienten.ItemsSource = item.Ingredients;
```

Solved!